# data could not be added to sqlite database on android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to make a login system for android. In this login system when user logs in then his details will be added to sqlite database so when he open this app again he will remain be logged in. The problem currently is that when I am calling addUser() method in DatabaseHandler class it says no value for uid. But when I display json data in logcat it show uid value. I do not know where am I making mistake. Please help me. Here is my code

LoginActivity

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
EditText email, password;
Button loginButton, btnLinkToLoginScreen;
TextView login_error;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
    password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
    loginButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    login_error = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.login_error);
    btnLinkToLoginScreen = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);

 // JSON Response node names
    String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    String KEY_ERROR = "error";
    String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
    final String KEY_UID = "uid";
    final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            //loginButton.setEnabled(false);
            final String useremail = email.getText().toString();
            final String userpassword = password.getText().toString();
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), useremail, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //Log.e("useremail ", useremail);
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), useremail, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(!useremail.isEmpty() && !userpassword.isEmpty()) {
                UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(useremail,userpassword);
                /*************************************************/
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = json.getJSONObject("user");
                    Log.e("son", obj.getString(KEY_UID));
                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                /**************************************************/
                try {
                    if(json != null && json.getString("success") != null) {
                        login_error.setText("");
                        String res = json.getString("success");
                        if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {
                            //loginButton.setEnabled(true);
                            //store user in SQLITE
                            // user successfully logged in
                            // Store user details in SQLite Database
                            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                            JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");
                            String s = json_user.getString("name") + ", " + json_user.getString("email") + ", " + json.getString("uid") + ", " + json_user.getString("created_at");
                            Log.e("String: ", s);
                            // Clear all previous data in database
                            userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                            db.addUser(json_user.getString("name"), json_user.getString("email"), json_user.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString("created_at"));
                            //store user in SQLITE ends

                            //launch dashboard screen
                            //Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);
                            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                    DashboardActivity.class);

                            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                loginButton.setEnabled(true);
                login_error.setText("Enter username and password");
            }
        }

    });

    btnLinkToLoginScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Here is my DatabaseHandler class

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "android_api";

// Login table name
private static final String TABLE_LOGIN = "login";

// Login Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
            + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ")";
    Log.e("Query: ", CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOGIN);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * Storing user details in database
 * */
public void addUser(String name, String email, String uid, String created_at) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Log.e("Data", uid);
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Name
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
    values.put(KEY_UID, uid); // Email
    values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at); // Created At
    Log.e("Values: ", values.toString());
    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

/**
 * Getting user data from database
 * */
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
    HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
        user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
        user.put("uid", cursor.getString(3));
        user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(4));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    // return user
    return user;
}

/**
 * Getting user login status
 * return true if rows are there in table
 * */
public int getRowCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
    db.close();
    cursor.close();

    // return row count
    return rowCount;
}

/**
 * Re crate database
 * Delete all tables and create them again
 * */
public void resetTables(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // Delete All Rows
    db.delete(TABLE_LOGIN, null, null);
    db.close();
}

}
```

Here is logcat

```
06-01 07:38:43.111: W/KeyCharacterMap(32734): No keyboard for id 0
06-01 07:38:43.111: W/KeyCharacterMap(32734): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
06-01 07:38:43.316: D/CLIPBOARD(32734): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
06-01 07:38:43.316: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(32734): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
06-01 07:38:48.346: D/dalvikvm(32734): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 100K, 47% free 3040K/5639K, external 357K/661K, paused 20ms
06-01 07:38:49.521: W/KeyCharacterMap(32734): No keyboard for id 0
06-01 07:38:49.521: W/KeyCharacterMap(32734): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
06-01 07:38:49.831: D/CLIPBOARD(32734): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
06-01 07:38:49.831: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(32734): showStatusIcon on inactive   InputConnection
06-01 07:39:49.646: D/dalvikvm(582): GC_CONCURRENT freed 115K, 46% free 3028K/5575K, external 319K/661K, paused 7ms+7ms
06-01 07:39:50.271: E/JSON(582): {"tag":"login","success":1,"error":0,"user":{"name":"Zafar Saleem","uid":"4fc0e87ec8ade4.83917704","email":"zafar@gmail.com","created_at":"2012-05-26 17:28:14","updated_at":null}}
06-01 07:39:50.276: E/son(582): 4fc0e87ec8ade4.83917704
06-01 07:39:50.276: W/System.err(582): org.json.JSONException: No value for uid
06-01 07:39:50.276: W/System.err(582):  at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
06-01 07:39:50.296: W/System.err(582):  at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:510)
06-01 07:39:50.296: W/System.err(582):  at com.zafar.login.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:74)
06-01 07:39:50.296: W/System.err(582):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
06-01 07:39:50.296: W/System.err(582):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
06-01 07:39:50.296: W/System.err(582):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-01 07:39:50.296: W/System.err(582):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-01 07:39:50.296: W/System.err(582):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-01 07:39:50.301: W/System.err(582):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
06-01 07:39:50.301: W/System.err(582):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-01 07:39:50.301: W/System.err(582):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-01 07:39:50.306: W/System.err(582):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
06-01 07:39:50.306: W/System.err(582):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
06-01 07:39:50.306: W/System.err(582):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
String s = json_user.getString("name") + ", " + 
           json_user.getString("email") + ", " + 
           json.getString("uid") + ", " + 
           json_user.getString("created_at");
```

to

```
String s = json_user.getString("name") + ", " + 
           json_user.getString("email") + ", " + 
           json_user.getString("uid") + ", " + 
           json_user.getString("created_at");
```

in line number 74 of LoginActivity.java